# excessive systemd-resolv queries on Ubuntu

Tags: dns

im seeing a lot of random looking queries occurring on my laptop.  systemd-resolv is listening on 5355 and my network packet sniffer is seeing lots of queries from my laptop IP to 224.0.0.252 that look like the following:

```
aewfepnumefp
aheqtiqyacacmy
ajjjkljfty
akbbdroya
alhxidmgqw
aljivqlbx
atozcboeqznl
auiordvmglyxjfx
aungrifairwkfbr
avbczfxhdjxkffl
awkzirhwbiom
azjqvwzd
bbdumnrwm
bcgssagcic
bcvjjuud
bergqgnifabkyxs
blrjwrc
bomkbpcbnwo
```

Does anyone know how to establish what is generating these? Im running Ubuntu 17.10.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Its a Chrome DNS trap detectortron feature:

https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/just-some-weird-domains-being-logged/931